# Strange behavior with chartjs when starting up blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, chart.js, blazorise

I am facing a problem where the global defaults are set properly but the bar chart is not coming up from the bottom as intended. The next thing I ran into is when the page is reloaded sometimes no chart shows up and sometimes it works as intended. The defaults are set in a extra .js file which is implemented in my _host.cshtml file.

The versions I am using:

- chartjs 3.9.1
- Blazorise.Charts NuGet Package 1.3.1
- .NET8 RC1

Here are some things I am doing:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    stateContainer.PropertyChanged += StateContainer_PropertyChanged;

    using var dbHelper = new TelemetryDataHelper(dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(), appCache);
    eventNameCountByDateAndNameDataWithUserId = await dbHelper.GetEventNameCountByDateAndVersionAndSpecificNameAsync(EventName).ConfigureAwait(false);

    UpdateAllDatasets();
    await HandleRedrawCountByDateAndNameAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    await barChartCountDate.SetOptions(chartService.GetBarChartOptionsBeginAtZero()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await barChartCountByDimensionName.SetOptions(chartService.GetBarChartOptionsBeginAtZero()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await barChartCountByMetricName.SetOptions(chartService.GetBarChartOptionsBeginAtZero()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

```
public BarChartOptions GetBarChartOptionsBeginAtZero()
{
    var barChartOptions = new BarChartOptions
    {
        Scales = new()
        {
            Y = new()
            {
                BeginAtZero = true,
            },
        }
    };

    return barChartOptions;
}
```

I haven't found any related article or problem on this behavior. I expect it to load correctly and when refreshing the page, it should work every time and not partial of times.

Comment: This could be a rendering order issue. Have you tried setting a variable (ex: boolean) that you use to wrap around your chart (like for a loading) and only set this boolean to true when everything for your chart is loaded and ready ?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Yes I have a loading bool. I am setting it to false after this line of code `await barChartCountByMetricName.SetOptions(chartService.GetBarChartOptionsBeginAtZero()).ConfigureAwait(false);` mentioned above.
It is just this `isLoading = false;`

Comment: I also want to mention that I tried putting everything in a try/catch block and setting isLoading in the finally block but this is not working either.

Comment: Why did you expect a try catch to fix this ? Is your circuit raising exceptions when the chart is wrongly displayed ? Do you have any errors in the browser console ? Can you also confirm that your boolean prevents render and does not only show some UI ?

Comment: I tried it because I thought I could catch some errors, but there are no errors. Currently it is a bool which is setting a loading spinner instead of the charts. For example I have this in my .razor `@if (isLoading)
{
    <Circle style="margin: auto;" />
}`. In the else block there is everything else. I just wonder what is different in the previous versions chartjs, because everything working fine.

Comment: Try to draw the chart inside `OnAfterRenderAsync` like in the [documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/chart). Blazorise uses JavaScript for the charts so the code needs to go inside `OnAfterRenderAsync`.

Comment: I tried this approach, but when I do this the variable `eventNameCountByDateAndNameDataWithUserId` is null on firstRender.